# Can I make webpack read dependencies in another way than require-ing?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to adopt an old and large code base to use Webpack. What makes that hard and challening is that our build system builds the dependency graph out of a manually typed list of files(`controller.js`)

```js
// index.js

app.start();
```

```js
// app.js

window.app = function() { ... }
```

```js
// controller.js

module.exports = {
  files: [
    './app.js',
    './index.js',
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now I've tried to setup a webpack config with the entrypoint as index.js, but obviously Webpack can't know that `index.js` requires `app.js` to be loaded first(this is what we are specifying in a filed called `controller.js`).

So my question: Is it possible to tell Webpack that "These are my entrypoint dependencies, build a dependency graph out of these files".

We can't rewrite everything to use CommonJS´ `require()`